# How to set default font in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, font, default

Is it possible to modify the default fonts to be used from "MS Shell Dlg 2" to another?

If yes, where do I have to set it?

Comment: why in my setting attribute table always mandarin font? How to change into normal font?

Comment: I have tried this but that doesn't work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to settings, options. From here the Applications section has a Font option, unselect default and edit what font you desire.

I'm in 2.4, for reference.
[image: Choosing Font]

Comment: That is setting the font for the application.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the default font for the print composer items in Settings>Options>Layouts:

[image]

But I don't think there is a way to set one for the rest of QGIS, like labels. But the print composer is the most common place for fonts, so that should help a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default Font for Labels in `Settings > Style Manager`. This will only work for labels that haven't been set yet.

[image]